# How to insert a hex value in a particular position of a file in Python?

Tags: python, hex, hexdump

I want to append 2 bytes (0000) to the end of a specific file segment (in hex) without modification of existing data.

From:

```
00000    FFD8 FFE0 0010 4A46 4946 0001 0101 0048 0048 FFEE
00014    000E 4164 6F62 6500 ....
.....
```

To:

```
00000    FFD8 FFE0 0010 4A46 4946 0001 0101 0048 0048 0000 <---
00014    FFEE 000E 4164 6F62 6500 ....
.....
```

The problem is that a file can be really big (up to 50 MB), so I can't just make this tiny change and rewrite every single byte to a new file.

So, all I want to do is to expand an existing segment (by adding 0000) without touching the rest of the file. (And yeah, I know, that I can't add a new value to memory without shifting other addresses associated with data).

Is there any way to do it in Python?

Comment: It's not possible to add data - however small - in the middle of a file without rewriting said file. However, if you read and write the file in larger chunks it should be fast enough.

Comment: Sad. Thank you anyway.